# How to use admob ads in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How to use admob ads in corona apps?.i develop a game its totally free .so descried to integrate admob ads to my app?.and give example code to me

Answer (score 2):

Now Carona allows you to implement ads and is not so hard. No Pro or Enterprise needed.

Here is an example:

[corona-admob-example](https://github.com/coronalabs/plugins-sample-ads-admob)

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy Corona Enterprise and attach it on the native code.

Since I don't own Corona Enterprise I cannot give you example code.

Comment: thanks lot........yes i have corona pro account and did u explain how to attach the native code step by step

Comment: No dude, not Pro, I mean ENTERPRISE. Pro is 300 USD, Enterprise is beyond 1000 USD.

Answer (score 1):

Now The `AdMob plugin` offers easy integration of `AdMob ads with Corona Application` . You can find the Plugin official documentation here

https://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/ads-admob-v2/

For detail tutorial for Understanding the Corona ad system please check this link

https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/07/15/tutorial-implementing-admob-v2/

If you want to use `multiple Ad Networks` , Here is detailed official tutorial

https://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/11/19/tutorial-using-multiple-ad-networks/

And for the Sample Code of Corona Application with Sample Admob Plugin code

https://github.com/coronalabs/plugins-sample-ads-admob

Keep Coding